# How to manipulate particle-hair position/rotation/scale with python?

Tags: python, scripting, particles, hair

how do we manipulate a hair particle in bpy ?
there's many basic individual properties i'd like to manipulate with python.
mainly hair **position**, **rotation**, **scale** and a way to **delete** some ? or make some **invisible** ? i'm not sure what's possible to do ?

[image]

here i have my suzanne with some hairs
let say that i want to replace thoses hairs by a custom matrix of mine:

```
hair_matrix = #xyz location, xyz rotation, scale
[
  [[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[2,2,2],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[3,3,3],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[4,4,4],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[5,5,5],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[6,6,6],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[7,7,7],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[8,8,8],[1,1,1],[1]],
  [[9,9,9],[1,1,1],[1]],
]
```

is there a fast access to a hair matrix like so? or i will need to do my own function and assign individually position, rotation and scale ? i suppose there's a foreach_get/set i could use ? i'm not sure **where i need to find the properties.** i saw that there's some weird despgraph manipulation to do. the data seem a bit hidden but i may be wrong ?

**also, let say that i'd like to delete/hide particles located above 50cm in Z height position, possible to do so ?**

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142741/how-do-i-programmatically-set-hair-position-and-shape-in-blender-2-8