# Is there a bounding boxes for particle system objects?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view

Is there a way to show bounding boxes for particle system objects and find their min/max coords?

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/143820/15543

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if their are bounding boxes for Particle systems but one way to create bounding boxes is by assigning the "**Collision" property to a 3d Object like a Cube containing the Particle system** and then treat it as a bounding box.
The below simulation is done by using a Wind Force field and using icospheres objects for Particle System under Newtonian Physics. The bounding Box -**Cube** in this case is provided the **collision property under the Physics tab and its Z-tranperncy alpha (under material) is set to "0"**.

However,inorder **to show the limits of the Bounding Cube** ,if a **wireframe modifier** is used the **collision property no longer applies** and there is no bounding.
[image]

Comment: that's not gonna work for me

Answer (score 0):

just iterate through the particles
e.g.

```
largest = {x:0,y:0,z:0}
particle_system = bpy.context.object.particle_systems[0]
    for particle in particle_system.particles:
        for axes in particle:
            for axis in largest:
                if axis < axes:
                     axis = axes
print(largest)
```

Comment: btw this isn't the greatest code, kinda rushed